# How to calculate permutations for a collection, not a set

Tags: java, algorithm, math

Suppose we have the following collection of integers: {1,1,2}. We can arrange the order of this collection in 3 possible ways:

1,1,2

1,2,1

2,1,1

How can we calculate the number of ways we can arrange a collection of integers in general? Suppose the size of the collection is very large (10^5 in worst case scenario) but the answer is always small enough to fit into a long. Does an efficient solution to this problem exist, and if so, how could one implement it in Java?

Comment: [Have you looked in Wikipedia?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets)

Comment: Are you asking how to code this in Java?  Or are you asking what the mathematics of it is?  And can you please clarify what you mean by "... the size of the collection is very large ..." - how large?

Comment: You mention that the integers are between 1 and 10^9, but that doesn't seem relevant to me. What would be relevant is: how big might the collections be? If they only store up to 20 items, the answer already given will work. But if you have more than 20 items to deal with, `n!` will overflow any of the Java primitives.

Comment: In the worst case scenario there would be 10^5 items in the collection (1,1,1...) Definitely more than 20 items in almost any scenario. I would prefer an answer in mathematics and try to work out the code by myself. Peter's answer seems promising, I'll have a better look at it tomorrow.

Comment: You might find it useful to read up on the `BigInteger` class.  If you've got `10^5` items in your collection, you're going to need it.  Also, you might find that Peter's answer doesn't perform particularly well with collections of that size.  You may end up writing code that takes a very long time to run.

Comment: I appreciate the answers, but I couldn't figure out how to implement this in Java and I fear that it would run too slowly even if I managed to implement it. Maybe there is no efficient solution to this problem? Also, why is this marked as "too broad"? I thought it was a really specific question and Peter and Gilbert provided some really specific answers. I edited the question further, but can't think of any way to make it more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have n integers made from n_i copies of integer x_i.

To work out the number of arrangements simply compute

```
t = n!
```

However, as you don't care about how numbers with the same value are arranged, for each value of i reduce the total by:

```
t = t / n_i!
```

In you case, you have 3 integers, with 1 copy of 2, and 2 copies of 1.

You compute:

```
t = 3! = 6
t = t/1! = 6/1 = 6
t = t/2! = 6/2 = 3
```

so the answer is 3.

Comment: `n!` overflows very quickly in Java... 21! is too big to store in a Java long.

Answer (score 0):

> How can we calculate the number of ways we can arrange a collection of integers in general?

Loop through the collection, counting the number of times each number appears in the collection.

The formula for the number of permutations is `size factorial / number of duplicate integers factorial`.  In your example of 1, 1, 2, the size is 3 and the number of duplicate integers is 2.

3! / 2! = 3 * 2 * 1 / 2 * 1 = 3;

Another, more computer friendly way of calculating 3! / 2! is to divide out the 2 factorial first, which leaves you with 3.

If the collection has no duplicate integers, then the number of permutations is `size factorial`.